# Git Action showing Permission Denied: I have an error when trying to read a JSON file

Tags: bash, git, shell, github-actions, workflow

Git Action showing Permission Denied: I have an error when trying to read a JSON file.

Running

`./src/script.sh '/home/runner/work/<Test>/<Test>/test.json'`

I get the following error code:

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/********-***-***-***-*********.sh: line 1: /home/runner/work/<Test>/<Test>/test.json: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.
```

What permissions do I need to add?

Comment: There are a few things you can try to resolve your issue:

1. Check the permissions on the file: Make sure that the file is readable by the user running the action. You can check the permissions on the file by running the following command: `ls -l /path/to/file`

2. Specify the user/group running the action: You can try specifying the user/group running the action in the run step of your workflow. For example:

```yaml
- name: Read JSON file
  run: cat /path/to/file.json
  user: myuser
```

This will run the `cat` command as the `myuser` user.

Comment: 3. Use `sudo`: You can try using sudo to run the cat command with elevated privileges. For example:

```yaml
- name: Read JSON file
  run: sudo cat /path/to/file.json
```

4. Check the file path: Make sure that the file path is correct and that the file exists at the specified location.

If none of these solutions work, it's possible that there is another issue with your GitHub Action setup.

Comment: After running ```ls -l /path/to/file```: 
I only have reading permissions (```-rw-r--r--```)

Comment: You could run a `chmod -x` locally and push the file with the updated permission to the repository afterward, just to check if it changes something.

Comment: ````chmod -x```` seemed to have done the trick, thank you

Comment: Great! I'll add it as official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, using the `ls -l /path/to/file` command showed that the file had reading permissions (`-rw-r--r--`).

Using the `chmod -x` command to update the filesystem permission set locally, and pushing the file back with the updated permission to the repository resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error due to using a container manager that does not require root (podman). Here is how I got around the error:

```
podman run \
   -t \
   -v .:/path checkmarx/kics \
   scan -p /path --verbose \
   | tee kics.log
```

Instead of writing the log to the container dir `/report`, which is a mounted volume from the host, the command outputs the log to stdOut then pipes it to `tee`. In turn tee writes the log on the host.

Hope this helps.